# How to use SELECT request in stored procedure (Oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I use **Oracle 12c**. I know that my next question is not new but I am little bit confused and need help.

I have this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE CREATE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(FIRST_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
                      AND TO_DATE(SECOND_DATE , 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Questions:

1. How correctly to use `SELECT` request in stored procedure?
2. That SQL statement returns more than 1 row, is it mean that I need to use cursor?
3. If table has 15 columns, as output I need to set all of them?

**EDIT**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_NAME
(
    FIRST_DATE IN VARCHAR2(10),
    SECOND_DATE IN VARCHAR2(10)
)
AS
    oracle_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN oracle_cursor FOR
        SELECT *
        FROM scheme_name.table_name
        WHERE CREATE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(FIRST_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE(SECOND_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(oracle_cursor);
END PROCEDURE_NAME;
```

Comment: Try `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1#return_result

Comment: There is not error on your `select` statement, however I suggest you define columns instead "*". And `'select` returns a result-set and you do not need cursor.

Comment: What are you going to do with the selected data? Process it in your stored procedure? Or pass it to another program to use?

Comment: @KaushikNayak thank you for the link. I used the information from that link to create PROCEDURE. Can you check my post again, I add it. Is it correct or not?

Comment: @MohammadMohabbati ok, can you check my post again. I add code of my PROCEDURE. Is it correct or not in your opinion?

Comment: @APC well, let me try to explain. I send 2 parameters which selected user through the php application to the stored procedure in ORACLE. Then I need to take the result and show that data in web page.

Comment: Just a note, every `SELECT` statement and even every DML statement like `DELETE`, `UPDATE` or `INSERT` creates a CURSOR. You actually should ask "... I need to use an **explicit** cursor?" A plain SELECT creates an IMPLICIT CURSOR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How correctly to use SELECT request in stored procedure?

In a stored procedure you need to assign the queried result set to a variable (or variables) which match the projection:

```
select << column >>, << column >>
into << variable >>, << variable >>
from table_name
....
```

> That SQL statement returns more than 1 row, is it mean that I need to use cursor?

A cursor is one way of handling it. Although a cursor loop is usually the better approach:

```
for r in ( SELECT * 
           FROM TABLE_NAME
           WHERE CREATE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(FIRST_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
                  AND TO_DATE(SECOND_DATE , 'YYYY-MM-DD')

) loop
```

Populating a collection variable is another approach, using the BULK COLLECT:

```
select << column >>
bulk collect into << collection >>
from table_name
....
```

> If table has 15 columns, as output I need to set all of them?

You can choose to create fifteen distinct variables. However, if your query's projection matches the table's projection (which it does with `select *`) you can use the `%rowtype` construct to define a record variable or a collection:

```
declare
    l_rec TABLE_NAME%rowtype; -- single row

    type t_rec is table of TABLE_NAME%rowtype; -- multiple rows
    l_recs t_rec
begin

    SELECT * 
    bulk collect into l_recs
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE CREATE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(FIRST_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
              AND TO_DATE(SECOND_DATE , 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

> I need to take the result and show that data in web page.

For returning results you probably just need to return a Ref Cursor. This is just a pointer which maps to constructs like JDBC ResultSet and ODBC ResultSet. For PHP this would be an `oci_new_cursor`. [Find out more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-new-cursor.php).

```
 Create or replace procedure get_recs
   (FIRST_DATE in varchar2, 
       SECOND_DATE in varchar2,
    OUT_RECS out sys_refcursor 
  ) is
Begin
    Open out_recs for
    SELECT * 

    FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE CREATE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(FIRST_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
              AND TO_DATE(SECOND_DATE , 'YYYY-MM-DD');
End;
```

Incidentally, you seem to expect to  pass the parameters as strings: it would be better to pass them as actual dates.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, bro! :) By the way, can you check my post one more time, pls? I add code of my current procedure. Is it correct or not? Can I ask you one more question? My PHP (5.5) application located in "Windows Server 2008 R2". Oracle 12c Database localed in another remote server. I tried to use `oci_connect` to connect oracle and php. Is it necessary to install "Instant Client" to server where php application located?

Comment: That's really a different question. I'm not a PHP hound but it's usual to install the Oracle client libraries in the same location as a client which needs to connect to Oracle.